# Google Compute Engine automatically shutdowns with serial console errors

Tags: virtual-machines, google-compute-engine, boot

I was upgrading the system specs of a VM I have.
I shutdown the VM, edit, increased the specs and then started it back up.

After doing this, it would just power back off after a moment online.
Checking the serial console I see this:

```
Could not create MokListRT: Volume Full
Could not create MokListXRT: Volume Full
Could not create SbatLevelRT: Volume Full
Something has gone seriously wrong: import_mok_state() failed: Volume Full
```

(120GB disk, 50GB used)
OS Ubuntu 20.04.4
From: `e2-medium  | 1vCPUs | 4GB RAM`
TO:   `e2-standard  | 2vCPUs | 8GB RAM`

I have been able to resolve this by creating a new VM with the desired specs and attaching the disk from the original VM as the boot disk.

If I attach a new disk to the original VM, it continues to have the same issue/error.. I'm mostly just curious as to what went wrong, seems like the VM itself got corrupted - is that possible?

Comment: Can you post the OS specifications and the details of the changes you did to the VM?

Comment: Yeah sure - Added to the post

Comment: Having replicated your environment and the changes you made, I did not experience any problem at all. If you want to dig into your issue, I suggest you open a support case with Google, which you can do through this link: https://cloud.google.com/support-hub

Answer (score 0):

In case someone bumps into this issue, this is likely due to the security measures in the VM being triggered and preventing a boot. Try to disable SecureBoot, vTPM and Integrity Monitoring (you may need to experiment to see which one fits your case) to see if that allows you to start your machine.

That being said, I do recommend logging a Google support ticket as per Gabriel Robledo Ahumada's comment.